# Is there a way to import multiple excel sheets using code in SAS Enterprise when DBMS errors occur?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I wrote some code with the hope of importing multiple sheets, but I receive an error:
"ERROR: DBMS type XLSX not valid for import."

I looked into the error and tried XLS etc, and then checked

```
proc setinit; run;
```

The output did not include  "---SAS/ACCESS Interface to PC Files" in which case I see that the advice is to use a csv file instead.  That would be fine, except I am trying to import dozens of sheets in a macro (see below) from a single excel workbook.  I'm not sure that it makes sense to save each sheet as a csv so that the macro can pull in all of the files.  That would be labor intensive in the future, as these sheets will be updated maybe multiple times a year.

```
%let path = 'C:/Desktop/Folder';

%macro importsheet(sheet);
proc import out= &sheet
    datafile = &path
    dbms=XLSX replace;
    getnames=yes;
run;
%mend;

%importsheet(sheet1);
```

My core question is this: 
Is the csv option the only/best solution for what I am asking?  My back up plan is to just do an autoexec, but I would like to make sure I've thoroughly explored writing a macro and discarded it as an option before I do that.

Comment: Do you have any SAS/ACCESS items listed ? (Such as ODBC or OLE DB) ? Do you have MS Office installed on your machine ? Is the EG session using a Profile connected to a remote server ? What version of EG are you using ?

Comment: In the Docs you will find [Using DDE to Read Data from Microsoft Excel](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=hostwin&docsetTarget=n1aqiv6biqkjbnn1gu1388hp7aab.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en).  There are many [conference papers](https://www.lexjansen.com/) about reading Excel data.

Comment: Your code doesn't use the SHEET parameter so how is it importing an Excel sheet? Do you have non macro working code? That's the first step, write code that works without a macro and then convert to a macro.

Comment: Enterprise Guide doesn't require the Access to PC Files to import an Excel file but I believe you need to use the point and click interface in that case. If you need a macro to convert your xlsx files to csv see the VB script here: https://gist.github.com/statgeek/878e585102c14e01581f55dbe972d27e

Answer (score 1):

The fastest and easiest way to import all Excel Sheets is to use a libname reference.

```
libname myXL xlsx 'path to xlsx file';

proc copy in=myXL out=work; run;
```

This will not work if you're importing from a specific range.

Comment: The XLSX library engine is only available if SAS/ACCESS Interface to PC Files is licensed and installed.